# nagio-nrpe server debain 9 strech

Tags: linux, command-line, plugins, nagios, icinga2

```
nrpe[15987]: Error: Request contained command arguments!
Jun 17 13:40:39 ip-XXXXX nrpe[15991]: Error: Request contained command arguments!
```

I am getting above error checked nrpe.cfg file `dont_blame_nrpe=1`

```
command[check_hda1]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$ -c $ARG4$ $ARG5$ $ARG6$
command[check_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -m PROCS -c $ARG1$  --ereg-argument-array $ARG2$
command[check_memory]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -u G
command[check_service]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_systemd_service.sh $ARG1$
```

syslogs show above error and deamon log show above error

checked all the provided solutions not working.

Is this the issue not with nrpe-nagios-server?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I can't tell what the question is here. I see you are getting an error. Please explain what you are trying to do. Then explain what is not working. Is nagios not performing an expected task?

Comment: from icinga i am running commands to check load ,check service but it is not running. When I looked into zookeeper instance where my nagios-nrpe-server is running I am able to see nrpe[15987]: Error: Request contained command arguments!  and bailing out request errors.